# mapping pid to qdbus service numbers after launching

Tags: bash, dbus, pid, qdbus

I am trying to write a bash script which will launch a program (konsole) and send dbus messages to it. Here is my experiment

```
konsole &
echo pid is $!
ps aux | grep konsole
qdbus | grep konsole
```

This outputs

```
pid is 2726
me    2726  0.0  0.4  45404  9952 pts/0    S+   14:59   0:00 konsole
 org.kde.konsole-2729
```

The qdbus service name is always `org.kde.konsole-{pid+epsilon}` but the epsilon part is unpredictable.

In my bash script, how do I get the exact qdbus service name for the particular konsole instance I just spawned?

---

Here's a nasty, hacky solution

```
qdbus | grep konsole | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' > /tmp/before
konsole &
sleep 1
qdbus | grep konsole | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' > /tmp/after

N=`sort /tmp/before /tmp/after | uniq -u`
```

but surely there's a better way!

Answer (score 0):

Try launching new Konsole instance via D-Bus API with `qdbus org.kde.konsole /Konsole newSession`. It will return session ID that can be later used to control it with calls to `/Session/$SID` object of the `org.kde.konsole` service.

Comment: `Service 'org.kde.konsole' does not exist.` but if I launch konsole manually then service `org.kde.konsole.12345` (or similar) exists. `qdbus | grep konsole` lists no results unless I am running at least one konsole.

Answer (score 0):

you can check PPID of qdbus, to see associated konsole.